# Customize Query for post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

The current query to fetch the data of my post type is taking too long, almost a minute to render 46 thousand records. Is there a filter or an action to customize the SQL function, and the markup generated in the admin panel, for this post type?

The plugins that I'm using: Advanced Custom Fields, WordPress SEO

```
function add_custom_groupon() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Groupon Codes',
        'singular_name'      => 'Groupon Code',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New Code',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Code',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Code',
        'new_item'           => 'New Code',
        'all_items'          => 'All Codes',
        'view_item'          => 'View Code',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Codes',
        'not_found'          => 'No codes found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No codes found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Groupon'
    );    
    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'groupon' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title' )
        );    
    register_post_type( 'groupon', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_groupon' );
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit please. You have a CPT with 46.000 items and when you access the admin page for this CPT it is slow? Do you have any other plugins? Can you show the code for the CPT. We need more detailed infos.

Comment: Yeap that's exactly what's happening, I updated my question with more details

Comment: Okay have you tried the standard stuff: Disabling all plugins and switching to a default theme to see if the problem persists? In theory this shouldn't be a problem. Also as you are new here I'll give you a tip: People are more likely to help if you show some effort yourself by e.g. checking your text for proper uppercase, typos and formating. Just a hint ;)

Comment: let me tried, sounds a good approach

Comment: ok so I tried, is the same result

Comment: Do you have W3 Total cache plugin enabled? if it's poorly configured it can slow down the admin real bad.

Comment: Please install `Query monitor plugin` to see, if your server is not so slow. I am using ACF with 40 field groups and 150 custom fields total, query runs in miliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hierarchical` argument when [registering a custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) should be set to `false` which is also the default setting

> **hierarchical**(boolean) (optional)
>
> Whether the post type is hierarchical (e.g. page). Allows Parent to be specified. The 'supports' parameter should contain 'page-attributes' to show the parent select box on the editor page.Default: false
>
> **Note:** this parameter was planned for Pages. Be careful, when choosing it for your custom post type - if you are planning to have many entries (say - over 100), you will run into memory issue. With this parameter set to true WordPress will fetch all entries of that particular post type, together with all meta data, on each administration page load for your post type.

Comment: you're the master... XD

Comment: Glad my answer helped you solve your problem. Enjoy :-)